# Sparse Matrix file format and conversion

Tags: matrix, format, sparse-matrix

Are there any libraries in C/fortran which can read different sparse storage file formats i.e. matrix market format, rutherford boeing , howell boeing format and convert from one format to another.

Specifically I've a code that reads howell boeing format however the the matrix that I've is in rutherford boeing format. While in many case they might be compatible but not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yousef Saad's [sparskit](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/software/SPARSKIT/) library (written in Fortran) has some routines.